# How do I execute ssh via Robot Framework's Process library

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh, robotframework

I'm at a loss for what to think, here. There must be something I'm missing since I'm able to execute this perfectly fine in another, similar context, but not here. I am trying to run the following console command via Robot Framework for the sake of testing my system's reaction to a network outage: `ssh it@128.0.0.1 sudo ifconfig ens192 down` (the user & host ip are modified for posting here.)

To accomplish this, I'm using the following line of code:

```
Run Process    'ssh it@128.0.0.1 sudo ifconfig ens192 down'    shell=True    stdout=stdout    stderr=stderr
```

Now, I've executed this myself in console and saw that the result was an inability to ping the ip, which is what I want. So I know for certain that the command itself isn't a problem. What *is* a problem is the fact that I get the following result: `/bin/sh: ssh it@128.0.0.1 sudo ifconfig ens192 down: command not found`

That's fine, though, because I believe this is a simple issue of the ssh instance not having the it user's $PATH. For reasons described below, I'm going to guess its $PATH variable is empty. Thus, I modified the keyword call as such:

```
Run Process    'ssh it@128.0.0.1 PATH\=/usr/sbin sudo ifconfig ens192 down'    shell=True    stdout=stdout    stderr=stderr
```

The result of this command is as follows: `/bin/sh: ssh it@128.0.0.1 PATH=/usr/sbin sudo ifconfig ens192 down: No such file or directory`, which I believe to be referring to the items in the PATH attribute. I've tried several different things to determine what the problem could be, such as why it would be unable to find these files in an instance where, executed manually in the console, these directories are indeed present.

Given that I have less than a year's worth of experience with Robot Framework, I'm certain that there's just something I'm not understanding about the Process library. **Could I have an explanation as to what I am missing for this execution and, if possible, an explanation as to how I should be executing an ssh command via Robot Framework?**

A few extra things worth pointing out:

- The it user is brand new, having been created via `useradd it` and copying the home directory contents into its new space.
- I have already added an entry into the device's sudoers file to allow the it user to execute ifconfig without requiring password entry.
- On that note, I've sent the executing user's ssh keys over to the device such that it does not require a password to log into it as that user.
- I have attempted to execute several basic commands. I have intermittently gotten `ls` to work but have been unable to get a greater sense of what $PATH the Robot Framework ssh instance has because `echo` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: is there a reason why you dont use the [ssh library](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html)?

Comment: If i read the error correctly - it says  cant find a command `ssh it@128.0.0.1 PATH=/usr/sbin sudo ifconfig ens192 down`  .. This is because you have single quote around the whole command including the arguments passed to ssh .. Remove the quotes and add spaces to indicate each argument ...

Comment: It was the quotes. It was the STUPID quotes! I'm so used to other languages that require literal strings to be encapsulated in quotes that I keep forgetting not to do that here. As for the ssh library... I didn't know that existed. I've looked on the Robot Framework website regularly for libraries to use (such as Process) but it isn't listed there. I'll give the ssh library a try, thank you!